# libcurl how to request HTTPS in cpp

Tags: c++, curl, https

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
curl = curl_easy_init();


if (curl) {
    string html;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &html);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "D:\\certification\\DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt");

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    cout << "Error : " << curl_easy_strerror(res) << endl;

    cout << html;
```

The Error message is Unsupported protocol

The http site is okay but The https site doesn't work

What should I add in curl_easy_setopt()

Comment: Curl has samples for almost everything  https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/https.html Have you tried it?

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do? If you just want to send GET or POST requests to HTTPS then you don't have to do all of that

Comment: I tried that libcurl/c/https.html too

Comment: I want to GET requests

Comment: "Unsupported protocol" means your libcurl was built without HTTPS support...

Comment: Ya @DanielStenberg is right. You should build curl with HTTPS support.